# Cassandra CQL v3.0 & Composite Types

Tags: cassandra, cql

I was going through the documentation of [CQLv3.0](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/index)

Should we specify composite keys across updates and selects like 'a:b:1' incase my `comparator` or `key_validation` is `ascii`, `ascii`, `int`?

There is no mention on `<select expression>` in select or way to specify composite columns and rows in update too `<primary/composite key name>`

Expecting some help over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQL 3 takes care of managing the actual composite types and values for you. CQL 3 rows are not necessarily the same as the underlying Cassandra rows ("storage engine rows"). The composite values are abstracted into separate columns.

The example at http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1 may help in understanding the transformation.

Comment: have they totally transformed the concept of composite keys? As of I know composite keys are specified as column level keys and row level keys via comparator and key_validation_class. But it is not the same in the reference?

Comment: The concept is the same, but the way you can model it and reason about it has become easier. Like I said, CQL 3 does all of the messy stuff for you now.