# Creating composite COLUMNS (not keys) with CQL 3

Tags: c#, cassandra, composite, cql

[This article](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2474) discusses possible ways CQL 3 could be used for creating composite columns in Cassandra 1.1. They are just ideas. Nothing is official, and the Datastax documentation doesn't cover this (only composite keys).

As I understand it, composite columns are a number of columns that together have only one value.

How do you create them with CQL?

**EDIT**

I will be using C# to interface into Cassandra. CQL looks straightforward to use, which is why I want to use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950338/cassandra-cql-v3-0-composite-types the same question and answer is if you use multiple primary keys then the first is used as partition key and others represent composite column [specify all columns in primary keys to simulate cli version of composite columns]

Comment: @Tamil I know. But composite columns can be separate. There are many examples of this on the Net. One may wish to have a composite PK and multiple composite columns.

Comment: @Tamil, according to The Paul, you are correct!

Comment: Glad that you came to a conclusion :)

Comment: @Tamil You've obviously been working at this longer than me. I'm going to make a suggestion to Datastax on how to help clarify their documentation. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: Also, answers from other on SO confused me. See the comments on the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984367/cassandra-1-1-composite-keys-columns-and-hierarchical-queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a couple concepts confused, I think. Quite possibly this is the fault of the Datastax documentation; if you have any good suggestions for making it clearer after you have a better picture, I'll be glad to send them on.

The "composite keys" stuff in the Datastax docs *is* actually talking about composite Cassandra columns. The reason for the confusion is that rows in CQL 3 do not map directly to storage engine rows (what you work with when you use the thrift interface). "Composite key" in the context of a CQL table just means a primary key which consists of multiple columns, which *is implemented by* composite columns at the storage layer.

[This article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1) is one of the better explanations as to how the mapping happens and why the CQL model is generally easier to think about.

With this sort of use, the first CQL column becomes being the storage engine partition key.

As of Cassandra 1.2 (in development), it's also possible to create composite storage engine keys using CQL, by putting extra parentheses in the PRIMARY KEY definition around the CQL columns that will be stored in the partition key (see [CASSANDRA-4179](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4179)), but that's probably going to be the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Thank you for this. It makes sense now. I'd be glad to help with the Datastax documentation. Clear, technical documentation is one of my specialties. I know exactly what is needed to make this clear. How do I contact you?

Comment: By "create composite storage engine keys", do you mean partition key?

Comment: Who downvoted this answer and why? If you downvote, give an explanation.

Comment: No sure this answers the question.  The referenced doc doesn't explain how to build composite columns at the table (not column family) level, only composite keys.

Comment: @ChrisGerken I believe the documentation is the problem and Paul's answer is correct. I went back through, for example, eBay's blog on Cassandra (http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/), and what Paul says makes technical sense (now that I understand the context of the terms). I have noticed there is tremendous confusion on how Cassandra works. Others have incorrectly answered me on SO. Again... documentation is at fault.

Comment: @ChrisGerken what's the difference between a table and column family? They are CQL and internal names respectively for the same thing.

Comment: I'll wait to see your edit.  The issue I'm hung up on is how in a CQL create table you can define a column to have a composite type (and therefore value) or a composite name - regardless of how the implementation works under the covers.  If that's not what you were looking for then I'll address it by opening another question.

Comment: @IanC you can find me as `thepaul` on Freenode or OFTC.

Comment: CQL does not allow creating composite values directly, but starting in 1.2 it exposes Map, List, and Set value types.  See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections

Comment: @jbellis I read that page yesterday. Exactly what I need for my use case.

Comment: @IanC sorry, yes, by "storage engine keys" I did mean partition keys. That is, in 1.2, the partition key can itself be made up of multiple columns.

Comment: @thepaul I went into Freenode, didn't see you there. I'm not really familiar with IRC. What about good 'ol email, and we can connect from there?

Comment: You can email me at M8R-xafy1t@mailinator.com.

Answer (score 2):

With Cassandra, you store data in rows.  Each row has a row key and some number of columns.  Each column has a name and a value.  Usually the column name and value (and row key, for that matter) are single values (int, long, UTF8, etc), but you can use composite values in row keys, column names and column values.  A composite value is just some number of values that have been serialized together in some way.

Over time a number of language-specific API's have been developed.  These API's start with the understanding I describe above and provide access to a Column Family accordingly.  Hector, the java client API, is the one I'm most familiar with, but there are others.

CQL was introduced as a means to use Cassandra tables in an SQL/JDBC fashion.  Not all Cassandra capabilities were supported through CQL at first, although CQL is getting more and more functional as time goes on.

I don't doubt your need for composite column names and values (I believe that's what your asking for).  The problem is that CQL has yet to evolve (as I understand it) to that level of native support.  Whether or not it ever will is not known to me.

I suggest that you complete the definition of your desired column family schemas, complete with composite values if necessary.  Once you've done that, look at the various API's available to access Cassandra column families and choose the one that best supports your desired schema.

You haven't said what language you're using.  If you were coding in java then I'd recommend Hector and not CQL.

Comment: It's C#. Ok, I'll wait until the 1.2 release and see if there's an update. Otherwise I'll have to use something else at least for the table create process.

Comment: Inaccurate; CQL as of 1.1 can create and deal with composite keys in a more powerful and simple way than the old-and-busted thrift interface. As of 1.2, the difference between thrift and CQL is widening. It's pretty unequivocal that you ought to use CQL 3 for any new Cassandra projects.

Comment: I don't see anything in CQL that lets you define composite column names or composite column values at the CQL table level.  You can define composite row keys, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: The question was how to effect the creation of composite columns in Cassandra, not how to define them at the CQL table level. There isn't any good reason to create composite columns at the CQL table level; the whole intent of CQL 3 is to shift back the need for that sort of abstraction at the high level.

Comment: Then we'll have to disagree on the interpretation of the question.  User's shouldn't be concerned about internal representations.  I'm curious to see how the re-edit of the question goes, though.

Comment: I've edited the schema-in-1.1 blog post to use the terminology of "compound key" at the CQL level (which is modeled as composite columns in the storage engine) instead of "composite key," to reduce the confusion here.

Comment: @jbellis: I'm still waiting for someone to address the point I made in my answer about composite columns at the public CQL level - something I still see in the question and something I still see lacking in the CQL support.  I only see a bunch of datastax guys down voting my answer and ignoring the exact wording.

Comment: @ChrisGerken the exact wording of the question does not ask how to create composites at the CQL level. The question asker himself acknowledged that. I agree that users should not need to be concerned about internal representation, except that older Cassandra documentation talks about how composite columns help in certain modeling cases, and this user wanted to know how to take advantage of that power through the CQL interface. If you have a different question, that's fine, open a new one. Do include your use case so we understand why you want to create composite columns at the CQL level.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to create them with CQL?  What is your use case?