# Can I create a supercolumn as a dynamic column in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I want to create a supercolumn in the CF and also the column itself is dynamic column and want to order the column by its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. However, supercolumns are effectively deprecated. It's recommended to use composite columns instead. There are several articles on subject, for example: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1

Comment: Well, the composite columns/key concept is a bit confusing compared to super column, especially with poorly written document. But I guess it's the way to go. I finally figured out (sort of) after reading this question multiple times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338616/creating-composite-columns-not-keys-with-cql-3